# Perform an action when clicked on a menu item

Tags: java, menu, javafx-2, menuitem

```
btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
((Stage)btn2.getScene().getWindow()).setScene(new Scene(new Login()));
 }
});
```

This is the code to display new contents in the same window when clicked on a button. Now I want to display new contents in the same window when clicked on a menu item. I tried this code just by changing the button name with menu item name. But it didn't worked. How can I do it ?

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't give anyone much chance to help. What happened? Did you get any error message?

Comment: @James_D The getScene() cannot be used with a menu item.

Comment: Oh, it's a compile error. "Tried this code" implies (to me, anyway) that you executed it. Yes, MenuItems are not Nodes. You need to call getScene() on some Node in the scene graph, for example the MenuBar to which the Menu is attached.

Comment: @James_D Can you provide me an example ?

Comment: No, I don't know how your UI is set up. But at some point you put the MenuItem ("btn2") in a Menu, and you put that Menu in a MenuBar. Just call getScene() on the MenuBar instead of the MenuItem.

Comment: @James_D Should I edit my question with full code ?

Comment: No, just make the changes I suggested, and it should compile.